# Convert Select/Count SQL Command to Linq to Entities

Tags: sql, select, count, linq-to-entities

I have a problem with regards on count command using Linq to entities.
What I want to do is to count all the **gender** with the **civilstatus** of my **employee**.

**civilstatus** `0 - all ; 1 = single ; 2 - married`

I'm newbie with linq to entities
here is my code on SQL Command.

I dont know how will I convert this one.

```
select '0' as UserID, COUNT(a.Gender) as TotalCount from Employees a 
union all
select '1' as UserID, COUNT(a.Gender) as TotalCount from Employees a where a.CivilStatus = 1
union all
select '2' as UserID, COUNT(a.Gender) as TotalCount from Employees a where a.CivilStatus = 2
```

**like this**

```
UserID | TotalCount
0     | 10
1     | 7
2     | 3
```

**HINT** 
lets say I have 10 employees (male and female) I want to know how many of them is single or married.

thanks. =)

Comment: just a FYI, take a look at http://www.linqpad.net/ it might help you out

Comment: I could help you, but I don't understand the problem... do you want to count all possible genders? I could answer this very short: 2... Please be more precise!

Comment: it should count all the totalcount of all civilstatus with value of 1 ; with and value of 2

Answer (score 0):

This linqpad program groups employees by Civil Status, and then counts all members as well as male and female, I think that demonstrates the grouping you are after.

```
void Main()
{
    var employees = new employee[] { new employee {Id=1,CivilStatus=1, Gender='M'},
    new employee {Id=2,CivilStatus=1, Gender='M'},
    new employee {Id=3,CivilStatus=2, Gender='F'},
    new employee {Id=4,CivilStatus=1, Gender='F'},
    new employee {Id=5,CivilStatus=2, Gender='F'},
    new employee {Id=6,CivilStatus=1, Gender='M'},
    new employee {Id=7,CivilStatus=2, Gender='M'},
    new employee {Id=8,CivilStatus=2, Gender='M'},
    new employee {Id=9,CivilStatus=2, Gender='M'},
    new employee {Id=9, Gender='M'}};

    var result = from x in employees 
    group x by x.CivilStatus into g
    select new { CivilStatus = g.Key,
                    All=g.Count(), 
                    Male=g.Count(e => e.Gender=='M'), 
                    Female=g.Count(e => e.Gender=='F') } ;
    result.Dump();

}

class employee
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int CivilStatus {get;set;}
    public char Gender {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: that's not what im looking for. what I want is to get all the total count of all the gender (even if male or female)  with the status of 1 or 2 or all

Comment: lets say I have 10 employees (male and female) I want to know how many of them is single or married.

Comment: It does give you that information and a little more.  if you remove the two lines Male=g.Count(e => e.Gender=='M') and Female=g.Count(e => e.Gender=='F') the results are exactly what you have asked for.

Comment: it give me 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 value

Comment: Try downloading linqpad and pasting that code directly in and run as a c# program.  I get: {CivilStatus=1,Count=4},{CivilStatus=2,Count=5},{CivilStatus=0,Count=1}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var q1 = from a in context.Employees 

                    group a by 1 into g
            select new
            {
                UserID = 0,
                TotalCount = g.Count(),
            };
        var q2 = from a in context.Employees 
                 where a.CivilStatus = 1
                 group a by 1 into g
                 select new
                 {
                     UserID = 1,
                     TotalCount = g.Count(),
                 };
        var q3 = from a in context.Employees 
                 where a.CivilStatus = 2
                 group a by 1 into g
                 select new
                 {
                     UserID = 2,
                     TotalCount = g.Count(),
                 };
        var result = q1.Union(q2).Union(q3).ToList();
```